# Residual Representation of a Motive

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-representations, motives

Suppose we have $M$ a hypergeometric motive, and $\rho$ its associated Galois rep over $\mathbb{Q}_{l}$. Is there any easy/concrete way to find $\bar{\rho}$, the residual representation at a prime (in this case 2)? If we were discussing the Galois representation associated to an abelian variety, we would look for the $2$-torsion, but I'm not aware of an equivalent formulation here. Furthermore the primes of ramification are too large for complete tables of number fields, so we cannot use that method.

Comment: Do you know the traces of Frobenius on the ell-adic rep?

Comment: Yes, they are computable basically instantly with Magma for most smallish primes.

Comment: Can you define "find rho-bar", if you already know the traces of Frobenius for all unramified primes?

Comment: I want a number field K, specified as a polynomial, and an explicit isomorphism of the Galois group onto a matrix group, such that the image of Frob under this element is the image of Frob in the representation, up to conjugacy of course.

Comment: That sounds like a hard computational problem to me. I am not even sure I would know how to do it for the Jacobian of a high genus curve given by explicit equations. You say "we would look for the 2-torsion". In general your motive is some part of the Q_ell-cohomology of an algebraic variety so "we would look for the Z/ell Z-cohomology" instead. What I'm saying is that it's not really clear to me in what sense this question is any easier for abelian varieties, in practice. Is the answer "just look in the cohomology with coefficients in a finite field"?

Comment: That's the first step in Schoof-Pila. See http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/pila/Frobenius.pdf for the details of how we do much more over an abelian variety.

Comment: I cannot see how the linked pdf helps. Can you point to something more specific? This seems to be a method for computing the char poly of Frobenius for an ab var over a finite field -- but you said in your first comment that this was the bit you could do for the motive in question. I am still unclear about how the question is any harder for general motives for which one can compute char polys of Frobenius than it is for Abelian varieties.

Comment: What is the number field corresponding to the 2-adic residual rep of the hypergeometric motive H([2,2,2,2],[1,1,1,1],-1/256) then?

Comment: I don't know -- my point is not that your question is easy, but that in your question you seem to imply that the hypergeometric question is harder than the Abelian variety question. Let's agree that your question is hard. Here's my question: what is the number field cut out by the 2-torsion of the Jacobian of the curve y^2=x^7+x^5+1? My point is simply that I have no idea how your linked pdf helps. Let me stress that I have no idea how to do your question, I am just confused by how you have presented it -- it reads as "here's something I can do for abelian varieties, how to do it in general?".

Comment: If you give me explicit algebraic equations for the addition law on the abelian variety, then the n-torsion is easy to write down as a variety: it's the preimage of a point under certain polynomials. That's the first step in finding the trace of Frobenius with Schoof-Pila, by working over the n-torsion symbolically.